# protobuf-net and optional values

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm attempting to generate protocol buffers C# code from a .proto file and, unfortunately, protobuf-net is generating code that doesn't compile.

The specific part of my .proto that is causing a problem is:

```
// Counter value response
message RpbCounterGetResp {
    optional sint64 value = 1;
}
```

When autogenerated by protobuf-net using the command line tools `'C:\Program Files (x86)\protobuf-net\protobuf-net-VS9\protogen.exe' -p:detectMissing -ns:CorrugatedIron.Messages -i:riak_kv.proto -o:riak_kv.cs`

I get the following chunk o' uncompilable code:

```
[global::System.Serializable, global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"RpbCounterUpdateResp")]
public partial class RpbCounterUpdateResp : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible, global::System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging
{
  public RpbCounterUpdateResp() {}  

  private long? _value;
  [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name=@"value", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.ZigZag)]
  public long value
  {
    get { return _value?? default(long); }
    set { OnPropertyChanging(@"value"); _value = value; }
  }
  [global::System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
  [global::System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
  public bool valueSpecified
  {
    get { return _value != null; }
    /* this is the big that won't compile as there's no conversion 
       between bool and System.Nullable<long>
     */ 
    set { if (value == (_value== null)) _value = value ? value : (long?)null; }
  }
  private bool ShouldSerializevalue() { return valueSpecified; }
  private void Resetvalue() { valueSpecified = false; }

  public event global::System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
  { if(PropertyChanging != null) PropertyChanging(this, new global::System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName)); }

  private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension extensionObject;
  global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
    { return global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing); }
}
```

Are there additional protogen options that can be supplied to correct this issue?

Comment: well that's vexing; there is code in there to try to spot keywords and add the `@` prefix - I guess I missed one; I will need to fix that

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is caused by a C# reserved keyword conflict between the .proto property named `value`, which produces code that won't compile. Changing the name of the autogenerated property to `returnValue` fixes things... until the next time code is autogenerated.